# How can I find an element by onclick attribute value?

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid

I am wondering if it is possible to find an element by the onclick function?

For example:

```
<a class = "calculator" onclick = add(number1,number2);

<a class = "calculator" onclick = add(number2, number3);
```

And I want to get the first one and the only difference is the onclick function so I thought thats the way I could differ them. Looks so far like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("calculator");

console.log(elements);

for (var i = 0; i <  elements .length; ++i) {
elementsSpecific = elements[i]. //The missing part

console.log(delementsSpecific);
 }
```

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd ever need to do this. But for everyone's sake, don't use inline event handlers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792498/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-inline-event-handlers-in-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the onclick function by using

```
elements[i].getAttribute('onclick');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can, though I wouldn't recommend it. It's faster to use different ids. However, if you really want to do it this way...

```
var link = document.querySelector('a[onclick="add(number1,number2)"]');
```

If you don't understand it, read about [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector)

Comment: And if there is no ID? Or is there always an ID ?

Comment: id is an attribute, it will be there if you put it there, the same way as the `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty poor way of targeting elements (what if the onclick value changes?) but if it's all you've got then you can use an attribute selector and `querySelector`:

```
var el = document.querySelector('a[onclick="add(number1,number2);"]');
```

I would definitely exhaust other avenues of selection before resorting to this, however.

Answer (score 0):

Without using js frameworks and making it for crossbrowser you can do this.

```
var as = document.getElementsByClassName('calculator');
var element = null;
for (var x = 0; x < as.length; x++) {
  if (as[x].getAttribute('onclick') == 'add(number2,number3)') {
    element = as[x];
    break;
  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/feyaheji/1/edit?html,console

Answer (score 0):

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) is the holy grail of finding elements in the DOM:

HTML:

```
<a class = "calculator" onclick = "add(number1,number2);">First</>
<a class = "calculator" onclick = "add(number2, number3);">Second</>
```

JavaScript:

```
var d2 = document.querySelector('.calculator[onclick*=number2][onclick*=number3]');
var d1 = document.querySelector('.calculator[onclick*=number1][onclick*=number2]');

console.log('Second', d2);
console.log('First', d1);
```

Notice the `[onclick*=number2]` selector which matches elements with the attribute name `onclick` and the value containing `number2`