# Is it possible to simulate a click using something other than the id or the class?

Tags: javascript

How can i simulate a click in this element?

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="ExecutarLance('59272');" title="ExecutarLance" class="btn btn-custom3">LANCE</a>
```

Normally I simulate clicks using the `id (document.getElementById("id");` or the `class`, but this element does not have an `id` and the `class` indicated is the same for several elements on the page.

In this case, this element is a button and the only specific attribute of it is the `onclick`.

I just want to simulate the click on this button.

Is it possible to simulate the click using the `onclick` as a reference?

Comment: Not tested but `document.querySelector("a[onclick=\"ExecutarLance('59272');\"]")`?

Comment: You can trigger clicks on elements selected by _any_ means--relative position, attribute value, etc. You might ask why you're doing that, though. The right approach is generally not to trigger clicks but to call functions directly.

Comment: @caTS, use single quotes in your JavaScript and you won't need awkward backslash escaping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find an element by onclick attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22237383/1264804)