# Calling an internal Cesium function from outside the script

Tags: javascript, html, cesiumjs

I am coding a cesium app and I would like to call an internal cesium function that clears all primitives:

```
function clearAll() {
    primitives.removeAll();
}
```

when i do a button press. I know about cesium's built in toolbar buttons but I would like to use an html button I already have in place to call this function on click. It's located in:

```
<script>
require(['Cesium'], function(Cesium) {
    function clearAll() {
        //code here}
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No. If it's internal (and not exported) it will stay internal (private) until you change the library code.

Comment: Do you know how I would make the function public so I can access it?

Comment: Where do you want to access it? Where did you put your code if not in that `require` callback?

Comment: @Bergi I want to use a button in my html body like this <button value="clear" onclick="clearAll()">Clear</button> to call the function because I want to be able to alter my script without having to reload the whole script.

Comment: No. Just don't do this. Don't use inline event handlers. Please.

Comment: @Bergi Any reason why this is bad practice?

Comment: You could have done that search yourself, couldn't you? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5871640/1048572 http://stackoverflow.com/q/15792498/1048572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the top of our [Billboards example](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Billboards.html&label=undefined).  When `Cesium.Viewer` is constructed, it provides access to `viewer.scene.primitives` which includes the `.removeAll()` function, which is public.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var scene = viewer.scene;
var primitives = scene.primitives;

function reset() {
    primitives.removeAll();
}
```

As @Bergi mentions in the comments, typically you don't wire this up with `onclick` because you need access to scoped variables like the viewer instance.  Instead, give your button an `id` attribute, and use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) (or jQuery) to listen for the button click within that scope.

```
document.getElementById('myButtonId').addEventListener('click', function() {
    primitives.removeAll();
}, false);
```