# Javascript Method Not Working - Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, methods

Good Morning,

I am having difficulty firguring out why this following Javascript method is not working.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<!--Author: Alejandro Deguzman Jr-->

<html>
<head>

<title>Realtor Inquiry</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

/* <![CDATA[ */
function termAgreed() {
    if (document.getElementByID.checked == true) {
        window.alert("Works!");
        }
}
/* ]]> */

</script>

</head>

 <body>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="agree" value="Terms" type="checked" checked="unchecked">Agree with the Terms & Conditions<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What im am trying to accomplish with the code above is when the checkbox is checked a prompt will appear. I did'ny quite know how to search for this specific answer I was looking for.

Comment: Where in this code are you calling the method termAgreed()?

Comment: I'm calling this method in the body, I think. Well atleast it is where I want the method to activate. When the checkbox is checked the prompt will appear.

Comment: I don't see anything here associating the checkbox with that function. I suggest you read up on `onclick` events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) As suggested above you need to call your function inside your `HTML`. Use `onchange()` and call the function on change of check box.

2)You need to correct syntax of selecting element. its `Id` not `ID` and also pass the Id of `element` you want to select.

```js
function termAgreed() {
if (document.getElementById("agree").checked == true) {
window.alert("Works!");
}
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="agree" onchange="termAgreed()" value="Terms" checked="unchecked">Agree with the Terms & Conditions
```

Comment: Awesome, did exactly what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please mark it answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're not using getElementById correctly. You need to pass in the element you're looking to find. Like so, getElementById("agree"). And as others have already posted in the comments, you're not calling 'termAgreed' in your code.

Comment: I just realized that. I forgot to put the checkbox ID. How would i go about calling the method in my form? Should I use onClick? I just want the method to activate once the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Consider using jQuery for this. Create a click event for the checkbox, see if it's 'checked', then perform your alert based on that check. Here's the fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/5o6h4g8o/

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not familiar with JQuery yet. I'm still trying to wrap my head around Javascript.

Comment: @killQuotes: Have you even tried this line of code `getElementByID("agree")` before posting it as asnwer?

Comment: @Syed, No, I didn't, but I see it was a typo on my end. Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Yes i realized that I forgot to put the ID after I posted my questions, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your `termAgreed` slightly. Please note that `querySelector` is not available in [older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector). I added a portion at the end to add the `change` event to the checkbox:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<!--Author: Alejandro Deguzman Jr-->

<html>
<head>

<title>Realtor Inquiry</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

/* <![CDATA[ */
function termAgreed() {
    if (document.querySelector('#agree').checked) {
        window.alert("Works!");
        }
}
/* ]]> */

</script>

</head>

 <body>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="agree" value="Terms" type="checked" checked="unchecked">Agree with the Terms & Conditions<br>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelector('#agree').addEventListener('change', termAgreed);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see, this seems to be a more advanced way of using event handlers? I am not familiar with JQuery as of yet.

Comment: No jQuery here. Though I recommend looking into it if you start using more JavaScript. Though maybe not suitable for your usage, adding event handlers through JavaScript (what I did) is more maintainable as you add more JavaScript to your page. It is also generally accepted as a [best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792498/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-inline-event-handlers-in-html) (and [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/onclick-html-attribute/), see note after compatibility at bottom, for example).