# Drag label text into paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to copy a text of a label inside a paragraph by drag and drop the label in to specific path of the paragraph.

e.g.

```
<label id="var1">i am new to JavaScript</label>`
```

before dragging example

```
<p>i am a student and </p>;
```

when i drag the label at the end of the paragraph.

So the label text should be copied to end of the paragraph and it becomes.

```
<p>i am a student and  i am new to JavaScript </p>;
```

Comment: It sounds like you really, really should not be using `<label>` for this. `<label>` elements describe form controls (like `<input>`) you don't seem to have a form control anywhere near your code.

Comment: yap but it does not needs form control it can be done in javascript or jquery  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You can find working exmaple **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/e7rf4sz7/5/)**.

Add an `id` to the both elements (dragged and dropped), after that add attribute `draggable = "true"` to the element you want to drag.

Now use `ondragstart / ondrop` to add the instructions your want to do on start of dragging and on dropping the label, and prevent the default action of functions `ondragend & ondragover`.

Using `event.dataTransfer.setData` to store the text we want to copy and `event.dataTransfer.getData` to get the text and past it in the position we want on dropping.

**HTML :**

```
<label id="dragSource" draggable = "true">i am new to JavaScript</label>
<p type="text" id="dropTarget">Drop label here</p>
```

**JS :**

```
var dragSource = document.getElementById("dragSource");

dragSource.ondragstart = function(event) {
    var dataToCopy = event.target.innerText;
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", dataToCopy);
    return true;
};

var dropTarget = document.getElementById("dropTarget");

dropTarget.ondrop = function(event) {
    this.innerText = this.innerText +" "+ event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
};

dropTarget.ondragover = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
};

dropTarget.ondragend = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
};
```

**OR**

You can use javascript inline event handlers ([knowing that some developers see that it is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792498/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-inline-event-handlers-in-html)).

**HTML :**

```
<label draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">i am new to JavaScript</label>
<p type="text" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">i am a student and</p>
```

**JS :**

```
drag = function(ev) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.innerText);
}

drop = function(ev) {
    ev.target.innerText = ev.target.innerText +" "+ event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
}

allowDrop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e7rf4sz7/6/)**

**[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)**

Comment: thanks this helped me well in my semester web application

Comment: this is good example can u modify it that should be copied to the courser area in paragraph

Comment: but thanks for the example it will also help i will try my best if u help me than i will be thankful

Comment: **copied to the courser area in paragraph**, just replace `this.innerText +" "+ event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");` by `event.dataTransfer.getData("Text") +" "+ this.innerText;`.