# copy text from label into a specific paragraph clicked point by dragging the label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

i want to copy the text in the following label to the specific courser dragged point eg

<label id="text_to_be_copied" > i am a student </label>

so i have a paragraph below

<p> this is the content where i want to copy the label text by dragging the label tag </p>

as if i drag the label into the paragraph after the text "this is the content where i want"

label dragged after this point

so after dragging it will look like

<p> this is the content where i want i am a student to copy the label text by dragging the label tag </p>

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTML 5  Drag and Drop](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)

[Line DEMO on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJqPNb)

Running sample code:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.innerText = document.getElementById(data).innerText;
}
```

```css
label, p{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

p {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label id="text_to_be_copied" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> i am a student </label>
  
<p  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">  </p>
```

Comment: yes but i want to drag and drop in the courser pointed area @braj

Comment: as i am new to javascript and i do not have an idea of the builton function to detect the courser pointed area to past the label

Comment: i will do will u get me to the expert of the javascript api's thanks

Comment: I am a backend developer in Java. I don't have much knowledge in Javascript. I just read about HTML 5 and whatever I know about drag and drop functionality I added in the post.

Comment: i have posted a question earlier which was related to my question but that did not work for me that was related to my question https://jsfiddle.net/e7rf4sz7/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', function()
{
    console.log('input changed to: ', input.value);
});
```

you want to like this ..?

dragging one field value into another field

examples: http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/5kpeJ/

Comment: nop i donot want like this. A few minutes ago i have posted related post but there i was not cleared my answer it is some how done but this does not give me the result i want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760101/drag-label-text-into-paragraph

Comment: this matches some how to my answer but this only add the label text at the end of paragraph by dragging the label

Comment: i want to copy the label text in the courser drop  point of the paragraph thanks