# How to call a function when the table in HTML resizes?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table element in HTML which resizes dynamically. Whenever the table resizes, i want to perform some operations for rest of the application members to adjust themselves according to the table. How can I achieve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onresize attribute in your table

here is example

```
<table onresize="myFunction()">
 <thead>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
 </tboady>
<tablel>
```

Put function in script

```
<script>
myFunction() {
 alert('resize working');
}
</script>
```

Now you can work on myFunction whenever resize your table.

Hope this help you

Comment: relevent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792498/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-inline-event-handlers-in-html

Comment: okay, happy to help you incase if you have any problem in code in future :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute to your table

```
<table onresize="yourFunction()">
```

yourFunction() - function which will be called, when table resizes.

Or you can do it in JavaScript , using the addEventListener() method:

```
object.addEventListener("resize", yourFunction);
```