# javascript scope issue when trying to target an inside method

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I have a js file with code like this:

```
var myAnonFun = function (param1) {


function createHTML(){

.....
sHTML += "<select id=param1 onchange='makeCalculations(this)'  >";
}

var vText = document.getElementById("results");
vText.innerHTML = sHTML;


function makeCalculations(){
}

}
```

Then, in a HTML file I have something like this:

```
var createAnonFun = myAnonFun (param1);
```

The code inside the js file will work as expected. However, whenever a value is chnaged in the select html object created inside the js file, I will get an error stating that there is not makeCalculations function.

As far as I understand, the problem is that the select object is trying to reach a function from the global scope, and of course there isnt one there.

So my question is: how can I target the select object to the makeCalculations function inside the  myAnonFun var?

thank you in advance!

Comment: `return {makeCalculations}` from the outer function, then one can do `createAnonFunc.makeCalculations()` from the outside

Comment: Why don't you move it to outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`makeCalculations` is declared within `var myAnonFun = function (param1) {` so its scope is local to that funcion (it will not be accessible globally).

Your best bet is, instead of declaring inline event handler, use an event listener:

So instead of:

```
sHTML += "<select id=param1 onchange='makeCalculations(this)'  >";
```

Do:

```
sHTML += "<select id=param1>";

vText.innerHTML = sHTML; // Without this the following event listener will not work

// and when you are sure the <select> above has been added to the DOM
document.getElementById('param1').addEventListener('change', function() {
    makeCalculations(document.getElementById('param1'));
});
```

---

Another option (not recommended, though), is to make `makeCalculations` available globally:

Change :

```
sHTML += "<select id=param1 onchange='makeCalculations(this)'  >";
```

to:

```
sHTML += "<select id=param1 onchange='createAnonFun.makeCalculations(this)'  >";
```

And, at the end:

```
    function makeCalculations(){
    ...
    }
}
```

to:

```
    function makeCalculations(){
    ...
    }
    return {makeCalculations};
}
```

Note that for this to work, you must have executed somewhere (outside of a function):

```
var createAnonFun = myAnonFun (param1);
```

Comment: acdc junior, I thought that using inline event handler would be the same as using an event listener. Is there a difference between them, or the difference is how the function is set in the second one?

Comment: Using `addEventListener()` instead of inline is more of a readability and maintainability thing, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15792621/1850609

Comment: Then, in the first option, what you are saying is to pass the whole function as a parameter, right? If I only pass the function call, I will get the same scope problem, or not? thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "only pass the function call"? This `document.getElementById('param1').addEventListener('change', makeCalculations);` ? If so, this works, the difference is that the first argument of `makeCalculations` will be the `event`, not the element (which is why I passed a function that wraps to a call to `makeCalculations` with the element as first argument. OTOH, you can still get the element from the `event` object (in `event.target`).

Comment: acdcjunior, what I dont understand is what makes the addEventListener works if we are still just passing the method call. How the method will be found? The method still belongs to a private scope, right?

Comment: When you use inline, the handler function must be present in the global scope (`window.handlerFunctionName` must exist). When using `.addEventListener('event', handler)` the handler must exist only in the scope where `.addEventListener()` is called, not necessarily in the global scope. What do you think?

Comment: Amazing difference between the two. I didnt realize it before. Very good answer. It is working now. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could make `makeCalculations` available in the global scope:

```js
this.makeCalculations = function() {
  // ....
}

// Outside:

myAnonFun.makeCalculations();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sHTML += "<select id=param1 onchange='makeCalculations(this)'  >";`

you could use the following.

```
var selectElement = document.createElement("select");
selectElement.addEventListener("change", makeCalculations);
vText.appendChild(selectElement); //this or replace all contents of vText
```

This method also removes unnecesary string concatenation confusions.