# Get first tag textcontent of li box with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have the first tag of (name) of my li whenever the li box is being clicked. But currently my code will only display the tag that is clicked.

Here is link to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ehagk1d7/ because the exact same code doesn't seem to work in snippet.

```js
    function test() {
        console.log(event.target.textContent);
    }
```

```html
<li class="lijst" onclick="test()">
  <p>Naam, PraktijkNaam</p>
  <p>Adres</p>
  <p>Email</p>
  <p>Mobiel</p>
</li>
```

Comment: So, your question is why it is working in js fiddle but not in snippet here?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would need exactly when clicking on the list ?

Comment: `event.currentTarget.querySelector('p').textContent`

Comment: When I click on the list I want to get the Naam, praktijknaam to work with in my javascript function. But I only get the Naam,praktijknaam whenever I click on that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this` as a parameter to add the element the handler is attached to. You can then use this parameter in the handler function. `event.target` will refer to the clicked element which propagates to the `lijst` element, not the element the handler is attached to. `querySelector()` will return the first matched element.

```js
function test(el) {
  console.log(el.querySelector('p').textContent);
}
```

```html
<li class="lijst" onclick="test(this)">
  <p>Naam, PraktijkNaam</p>
  <p>Adres</p>
  <p>Email</p>
  <p>Mobiel</p>
</li>
```

Better would be to get rid of the inline event handler and define the event handler in javascript as in snippet below.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.lijst').forEach(el => { 
  el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(this.querySelector('p').textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<li class="lijst">
  <p>Naam, PraktijkNaam</p>
  <p>Adres</p>
  <p>Email</p>
  <p>Mobiel</p>
</li>

<li class="lijst">
  <p>Naam, Nog een PraktijkNaam</p>
  <p>Adres</p>
  <p>Email</p>
  <p>Mobiel</p>
</li>
```

Comment: I used your first solution. Thank you. The second one will only show the name of the very first li in my list.

Comment: @Captain Glad the first one works for you. I updated the second one too so it works with multiple `.lijst` elements. Using inline event handlers is considered a bad practice therefore I recommend you use the 2nd option.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792498/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-inline-event-handlers-in-html

Answer (score 0):

> use [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild)

```js
function test(el) {
  alert(el.firstElementChild.textContent );
}
```

```html
<li class="lijst" onclick="test(this)">
  <p>Naam, PraktijkNaam</p>
  <p>Adres</p>
  <p>Email</p>
  <p>Mobiel</p>
</li>
```

> If you want to stay with event element use [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) which is always the origin "node" of your function

```js
function test() {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.firstElementChild.textContent);
}
```

```html
<li class="lijst" onclick="test()">
  <p>Naam, PraktijkNaam</p>
  <p>Adres</p>
  <p>Email</p>
  <p>Mobiel</p>
</li>
```